# How to use Python PDFkit to produce pdfs from list of URLs?

Tags: python, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am trying to use the Python PDFKit module to work through a list of ~500 URLs like [this one](http://world.people.com.cn/n/2014/0228/c157278-24487785.html) and save the pages as PDFs. I don't need the pictures / links in these PDFs.

The code below produces PDFs of the webpages, but with just a load of garbage characters. Is this an encoding problem and if so how could I resolve it?

If I run it without the 'options' then PDFKit will produce a correct PDF from the webpage, but it goes very slowly and crashes often. I also don't think the first two options are specified properly.

```
import pdfkit
import re

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf")

options = {
    'disable-external-links': None,
    'lowquality': None,
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'custom-header' : [('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')],
    'cookie': [
        ('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
        ('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
    ],
    'no-outline': None
}

with open('/Users/.../PycharmProjects/RMWScraper/urllist_SCS_2014.txt') as f:
    list = f.readlines()
    for idx, URL in enumerate(list):
        print(URL)
        d = re.findall("20(.*)/c", URL)[0]
        date = d.replace("/","")
        print(date)
        pdfkit.from_url(URL, '/Users/..../PycharmProjects/RMWScraper/PDFS/'+date+'_'+str(idx)+'.pdf', configuration=config, options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this for my purposes by not using PDFkit, and using wkhtmltopdf directly - called from the Terminal using the following code to iterate through my list of URLs. It seems like 'wkhtmltopdf' is much faster when running with these options.

```
for idx, URL in enumerate(URLS):
     d = re.findall("20(.*)/c", URL)[0]
     date = d.replace("/", "")
     os.system("wkhtmltopdf --disable-javascript --lowquality --disable-external-links --no-images --load-error-handling ignore "+URL+" article_"+date+"_"+str(idx)+".pdf")
```